# Google drive api upload User rate limit exceeded

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-php-sdk

I'm using `PHP SDK` to copy files to **Google Drive**, my account can use unlimited storage

After 300-500 files uploaded, User rate limit exceeded show up and i can't upload until next day

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User rate limit exceeded."
}

function copydrive($driveid,$folder,$newname){
    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $newname,
        'parents' => array($folder)
    ));
    $result = $GLOBALS['service']->files->copy($driveid, $fileMetadata);
    return $result->id;
}
$newid = copydrive($episode['drive'],$folderid,$filename);
if($newid!=''){
    $qrun2=$conn->prepare("update episode set mydrive='".$newid."' where id=".$episode['id']);
    $qrun2->execute();
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo 'setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(1);}, 2000);';
    echo "</script>";
}
```

**Update** using batching request still getting error

```
$qrun=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM episode WHERE drive!='' and mydrive is null limit 50");
$qrun->execute();
$episode=$qrun->fetchAll();
$batch = $service->createBatch();
$num=0;
foreach($episode as $item){
    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'parents' => array('parent folder id')
    ));
    $result = $GLOBALS['service']->files->copy($item['drive'], $fileMetadata);
    $batch->add($result,'copy-'.$num);
    $num++;
}
$results = $batch->execute();
$total_rs = count($results);
for($x=0;$x<$total_rs;$x++){
    $qrun2=$conn->prepare("update episode set mydrive='".$results['response-copy-'.$x]->id."' where id=".$episode[$x]['id']);
    $qrun2->execute();
}
```

In API dashboard the request in 1 hour is 344

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because you're doing your request probably at a fast rate. I would suggest:

1. slowing down, like creating a delay in between requests.
2. If you can perform [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch#format-of-a-batch-request) then do so.
3. If it applies to you, try using other users to create the request under the project, like sharding the requests,.

Comment: I have try batching request but nothing change, still got error after few hundred file copied

Comment: that means you're hitting an internal limit then. two words, 'slow down'